# How to iterate over Mapping<K,V>?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I have a very basic question - ink! now has a [Mapping](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_storage/struct.Mapping.html) struct for `key-value pairs`. It seems it does not implement the `Iterator` trait?

Comment: You can check this answer:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-to-return-the-whole-mapping-from-a-contract-method

Comment: Vec is heap-allocated, what if I have a really large collection?

Comment: In the real reality, the question is NOT simple.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to iterate over a `Mapping` from a contract. We intent to implement this functionality soon. For more information check out this issue: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11410

If you try to iterate over a mapping off chain (from a UI for example) you could use the `childState_getKeys` RPC to list the keys of the child trie used by the contract in question.

Answer (score 0):

There are any alternatives for `HashMap` today `Mapping` that developers can use and have possibility to iterate?