# how to iterate a mapping with values as a struct

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I have a mapping that has values and I would like to iterate the map and display the results that satisfy the condition and return the results as the array. The function looks like this

```
fn iterate_map(&self) -> Vec<(AccountId, u32)> {
        let mut results = Vec::new();
        for (key, value) in self.my_map.iter() {
            if *value > 10 {
                results.push((*key, *value));
            }
        }
```

Now is it possible to do this action using ink smart contract?

Comment: iterating over a Mapping is not supported:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/how-to-iterate-over-mappingk-v

Comment: It is almost 9 months back and it is mentioned that the feature will be added soon. I just want to know if anything has come already.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah mapping doesn't support iterating. You can insert value in mapping as well as Vec at same time like:

```
pub struct A {
  mapping: Mapping<id, value>,
  vector: Vec<id>,
}
```

later you can iterate vector and display those value. As for example I have included example you can go through [this link](https://ink-playground.substrate.io/?id=7dddd51c98e9927d2bf33a05d9a6b887)

Comment: This is a good alternative except in cases where the mapping key is a string and the cost of storing it would be costly

Comment: yes if key is string then it may not be iterable