# Does it make sense to use HashMap instead of Mapping in ink?

Tags: ink, storage

I'm developing a contract that should have some type of a map from `AccountId` to `Balance` **and** I should be able to **iterate** over it.
Using `ink_storage::Mapping` I can't iterate over the collection. But using `ink_prelude::collections::HashMap` gives me the iterator methods I need but it consumes more gas.

So what is the best way to iterate over such a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, the ink prelude types are not optimised for contract usage and should be avoided if possible. `ink_prelude::collections::HashMap` increases the contract size compared with `ink_storage::Mapping`.

You can implement your [own indexes for Mapping](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/870/380) although there are [plans to create an iterator for it in future](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11410).

Comment: Yeah, I've already come up with the same idea of storing indexes in Vec, thnx